# Modifying the name of a variable within asset_path for use as an image

Tags: jekyll, assets, liquid

I am extremely new to Jekyll/Ruby/Liquid and I would like to create a for loop to display an image for every different tag that I have. However I can't seem to get it to work. I think the problem is nesting the name of each tag inside asset_path and then modifying the name. It keeps throwing the error that I have not properly terminated the variable.

For example, if one of my tags was 'cloud', I would like the 'cloud_logo.png' image to be displayed from my asset directory. I am using the jekyll-assets plugin and am running it all locally through terminal.

```
 {% for tag in site.tags %}
      <img src="{% asset_path {{ tag | first }}_logo.png %}"></img>
 {% endfor %}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much for your answer JootS! It helped me a lot, you were missing something though, for some reason `{{ asset_path }}` wasn't getting recognised, but when I replaced it with `/assets/` it was a temporary hotfix as my html file is in the root directory. So the solution was:

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
<img src="/assets/{{ tag | first }}_logo.png" />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct liquid:

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <img src="{{ asset_path }}{{ tag | first }}_logo.png" />
{% endfor %}
```

Note that you should set your 'asset_path' in your '_config.yml' file like this (for future reference):

```
asset_path: '/assets/'
```

Happy Jekylling!